# Transform Kotlin List to certain size by padding or concatenating the last n elements

Tags: kotlin, collections

I often need to either shorten or pad a List to a certain amount of entries. For that I use a function like this:

```
fun List<String>.compactOrPadEnd(size: Int): List<String> {
  if (this.size < size)
    return this + List(if (this.size < size) size - this.size else 0) { "" }
  else
    return this.subList(0, size - 1) + this.subList(size - 1, this.size).joinToString("")
}

val list0 = emptyList<String>()
val list1 = listOf("A")
val list2 = listOf("A", "B")
val list3 = listOf("A", "B", "C")
val list4 = listOf("A", "B", "C", "D")
val list5 = listOf("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")

val size = 3
list0. compactOrPadEnd(size).onEach(::println)   // [ ,  , ]
list1. compactOrPadEnd(size).onEach(::println)   // [A,  , ]
list2. compactOrPadEnd(size).onEach(::println)   // [A, B, ]
list3. compactOrPadEnd(size).onEach(::println)   // [A, B, C]
list4. compactOrPadEnd(size).onEach(::println)   // [A, B, CD]
list5. compactOrPadEnd(size).onEach(::println)   // [A, B, CDE]
```

The above code is more readable with separate functions:

```
fun List<String>.padEnd(size: Int) =
    this + List(if (this.size < size) size - this.size else 0) { "" }

fun List<String>.compact(size: Int) = 
    this.subList(0, size - 1) + this.subList(size - 1, this.size).joinToString("")

fun List<String>.compactAndPadEnd(size: Int): List<String> = 
    if (this.size < size) padEnd(size) else compact(size)
```

I find both solutions too clumsy. I went through all the built-in collection functions to come up with something simpler, but to no avail.

Small side question: is there a better name than *compactAndPadEnd?*

Answer (score 3):

You can write this as one case (i.e. without if-else) if you take advantage of the fact that `joinToString` happens to return your pad element `""` when the list is empty.

```
fun List<String>.resizeEnd(size: Int): List<String> =
    this.subList(0, min(size - 1, this.size)) +
            this.subList(min(size - 1, this.size), this.size).joinToString("") +
            List(max(0, size - this.size - 1)) { "" }
```

Notice that I'm creating a list of size `size - this.size - 1` at the end. `-1` because one of the empty strings would have been the one returned by `joinToString("")`.

If you don't mind `drop` and `take` creating extra lists, you can make it shorter:

```
fun List<String>.resizeEnd(size: Int): List<String> =
    this.take(size - 1) +
            this.drop(size - 1).joinToString("") +
            List(max(0, size - this.size - 1)) { "" }
```

You can also generalise this to:

```
fun <T> List<T>.resizeEnd(size: Int, padElement: T, foldFunction: (T, T) -> T): List<T> =
    this.subList(0, min(size - 1, this.size)) +
            this.subList(min(size - 1, this.size), this.size).fold(padElement, foldFunction) +
            List(max(0, size - this.size)) { padElement }
```

But the catch is that `padElement` must be the identity for `foldFunction`.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you could create a List of fixed size using an [initializer function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/constructing-collections.html#initializer-functions-for-lists) combined with a `when` to initialize each item:

```kotlin
fun List<String>.resize(size: Int) = List(size) {
    when {
        it == size - 1 && this.size > size -> this.subList(size - 1, this.size).joinToString("")
        this.size > it -> this[it]
        else -> ""
    }
}
```

I'm not entirely sure if this is any less clumsy, I suppose that depends on personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

I see some slight clean-up you can do on your function. You're redundantly checking `this.size < size`, you could lift `return` out of the condition branches, and you could use `take`/`drop` for brevity.

```
fun List<String>.compactOrPadEnd(size: Int): List<String> {
    return if (this.size < size)
        this + List(size - this.size) { "" }
    else
        take(size - 1) + drop(size - 1).joinToString("")
}
```

Personally, I'd call it `concatEndOrPad`.